# Infinite loop in State Change Events in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, events, state, infinite-loop

I want to change the state from **"mycarts"** state to **"carts"** state. so I used $stateChangeStart angularjs event in **"mycarts" controller** and set a condition if the state you are going from **"mycarts" state** is **"carts" state** so go to the carts state.

Here is my **angular event** in my controller :

```
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (toState.name === 'carts' && fromState.name === 'mycarts') {
            $state.go('carts', fromParams, true);
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        if (toState.name === 'mycarts' && fromState.name === 'mycarts') {               
            //Nothing
        } else {
            $rootScope.selectedItemsMyCarts = undefined;
        }
    });
```

My code will be stuck in :

```
if (toState.name === 'carts' && fromState.name === 'mycarts') {
        $state.go('carts', fromParams, true);
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
 }
```

Here is my state in app.js

```
.state('mycarts', {
        url : '/mycarts/:type/:vendor?vendors&price_to&price_from&manufacturer&editor&theme&page&order&filter_by&no',
        params: {
                    type: {squash: true, value: null}, 
                    vendor: {squash: true, value: null}
                },templateUrl : 'partials/mycarts.html',
        controller : 'MyCartsController'
    }).state('carts', {
        url : '/carts/:id?vendors&price_to&price_from&manufacturer&editor&theme&page&order&no',
        templateUrl : 'partials/carts.html',
        controller : 'CartsController'
    }
```

And I get **angular.js:12416 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

why this happens? And what is the solution if I want to change a state due to a condition in angular event? And what kind of documents I can read to understand what exactly going on when events like this happends.

Answer (score 1):

If he is already going to the carts state, why are you doing this? :

```
$state.go('carts', fromParams, true);
```

Comment: This is your problem, OP. If you are already in the $stateChangeStart handler and you are transitioning to the 'carts' state, you don't need to manually call `$state.go('carts',etc,etc)`. The state transition is already started - thats the whole reason you're in the stateChangeHandler to begin with. If you manually call it again, you're going to make the $stateChangeStart event fire AGAIN, which will change the state AGAIN, causing the $stateChangeStart event to fire AGAIN in an infinite loop.